# User interaction on a website without requiring registration nor captcha

Tags: web-development, user-experience

Are there succesful ways (i.e. non spammed by 1000 bots per second!) to propose some user interaction on a website such as :

- Voting up / Voting down / Liking posts
- Posting comments

but **without account registration and without captcha** ?

---

I have read that filtering by IP is not relevant, for many reasons (people may have the same public IP, if they work in the same company for example, and may want to vote on the same post, *without being a bot*).

[I have tried solutions with *honeypots* HTML items that bot may fill, and normal users would not fill, but I don't think this is enough to prevent spam to come.]

Comment: Perhaps, but account registration and Captcha (especially Captcha) are among the most effective techniques.

Comment: simple questions would help...`what color is a tomato?`, `what is one plus one?` stuff like that can be easier than a captcha for less computer literate folks.